# Why is the first line shifted one space to the right?

Tags: c++, file, loops

Okay so me and a few colleagues were working on an assignment for class. I completed it to my fullest extent; however, there is one thing that neither I nor any of my colleagues could fix. I searched for hours online but couldn't fine the answer I needed.

The first line that is printed after the data is read from the file is always shifted 1 space to the right. That is my only problem. The string is not shifted, but everything is. We checked for spaces, tabs, and extra symbols, we tried switching up the file we were reading from all to achieve nothing. I would really appreciate it if someone could point out what is wrong with my program. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

ifstream inputFile;

cout << "Please enter the file you would like to open: ";
string filename;
cin >> filename;

inputFile.open(filename);

if(inputFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Error: File failed to open or was not found..." << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "File opened" << endl;

    string land;
    double price, min, max, total, average, count;

    count = 0;
    min = 0;
    max = 0;
    total = 0;

    while(inputFile.good())
    {
        getline(inputFile, land, '\t');
        inputFile >> price;

        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(40) << left << land << right << "$   " << price;




        if(count == 0)
        {
            max = price;
            min = price;
        }

        if(price > max)
        {
            max = price;
        }

        if(price < min)
        {
            min = price;
        }

        total += price;


        count++;
    }

    inputFile.close();

    average = total / count;

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(43) << "Average Price =       $   " << average << endl;
    cout << setw(43) << "Highest Price =       $   " << max << endl;
    cout << setw(43) << " Lowest Price =       $   " << min << endl;

}



return 0;
}
```

What doesn't make sense to me is that it is a loop, so why is only the first one being shifted?

This is what was on the file I was using

```
Landmark    1258
Creekside   1840
Parkside    1575
Gallatyn Walk   1710
Oak Mill    1185
Cutler's Ridge  1495
Prairie Creek Cottages  1987
Waterview Mills 1505
Canterbury Courts   1300
Breckinridge Point  1205
The Junction    1699
```

The words and numbers should all be separated with a tab.

The Image shows the output I was always given.
[image]

Comment: The output doesn't seem to shift on my system.

Comment: it maybe xcode thing, try run it in terminal

Comment: Why getline(dlim = '\t') ?

Comment: Because the input file contains tabs.  They are using it to read the string before the tab.

Comment: Ran it in a terminal had the same outcome.

Comment: @paddy, yeah, it seems that this question didn't provide the right data, cause i didn't get any tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an illusion.  The first line is spaced correctly.  Every other value you read in with `getline` will include a `\n` character, which is where `inputFile >> price` left off.

A quick fix is to ignore all characters to the end of line after reading `price` (requires you to include `<limits>`):

```
getline(inputFile, land, '\t');
inputFile >> price;
inputFile.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
cout << setw(40) << left << land << right << "$   " << price << endl;
```

A better approach is to always read lines in the first place.  This is also a more correct loop condition, and a practise you should get into (this version uses `<sstream>`):

```
string line;
while( getline( inputFile, line ) )
{
    istringstream line_ss( line );
    if( getline( line_ss, land, '\t' ) >> price )
    {
        cout << setw(40) << left << land << right << "$   " << price << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am only allowed to use the statements I already have, sadly I can't use stream or limits I think.

Comment: In that case, you'll have fragile code.  The accepted answer assumes that there is no whitespace except a newline after the price.  If your lines are not expected to have leading whitespace, you could use [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) which _is_ in your toolbox, since you're prolifically using IO manipulators.  And the numeric limits is simply the correct way to ignore _everything_ until delimiter or EOF.  You could just as easily use `ignore( 10000, '\n' )`, accepting your program will have a bug where stupendously long trailing whitespace will break it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that from the first line, variable "land" is "Landmark" while all the others have the \n in front of the name, taken from the previous line, ie "\nCreekside", "\nParkside" etc.
You could just delete the \n from the string name and then add it at the end of your std::cout:

```
while (inputFile.good())
    {
        getline(inputFile, land, '\t');

        if (land[0] == '\n')
        {
            land.erase(0, 1);
        }


        inputFile >> price;

        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(40) << left << land << right << "$   " << price << endl;
```

Now the outcome is formatted correctly!

Comment: When I entered that on Xcode everything went out of control; However it seems to work in Code Blocks just fine. Any idea why it doesn't work in Xcode?

Comment: I think I will just go with this approach since I will be graded using Code Blocks. Thank you so much for your help!